# how multicast stream passes when receiving locally

Tags: linux, networking, routing, multicast

If suppose I have TX application which transmits UDP multicast to `239.0.0.1:1234`. And I have RX application which joins multicast (`239.0.0.1:1234`), and receives this multicast (`239.0.0.1:1234`).

I have this RX application running in different machines, and also in same machine where TX application is running.

RX application running in different machines (other than machine where TX is running) see packet losses regularly. Also, the packet that is loosing is same on all other machines. But, at RX application running in machine where TX application is also running, never see any packet loss. I am trying to solve this packet loss problem (at least minimize, because I get regular packet losses, increasing with time, on 1 Gbps network where TX application transmits around only 100 Mbps).

My question is: When RX application is running at machine which is same machine where TX application is running, then how multicast packets traverse. Does packets routed to RX inside same machine **after IP stack**? Does packets routed to RX inside same machine **after queuing disciplines**? Does packets routed to RX inside same machine **after NIC hardware queuing**? Does packets goes **to router/switch and then comes back to same machine**?